# Another Comparison Contract Violation

Tags: java, sorting

I give up. I'm sitting weeks on this in different locations in my code and this really "helpful" error message reappears again and again.
I could not find anything in the other posts, that would direct me to a solution,  but perhaps I'm just completely blind and dumbfolded.

What I do is this:

```
int compare = -1;
SomeObjectWithString other = (SomeObjectWithString) arg0;

if (this.getText() == null && other.getText() == null) {
  compare = 0;
} else if (this.getText() == null && other.getText() != null) {
  compare =-1;
} else if (other.getText() == null) {
  compare = 1;
} else {
  compare = this.getText().compareTo(other.getText());  
}

if (compare == 0) {
  //finally comparing hashcode when equal
  compare = this.hashCode()-other.hashCode();
}
return compare;
```

What I get - sometimes (depending on the data) is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
           Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Has anybody any idea, why the contract might not be fullfilled, as Blochs Exception message here is everything, but helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where have you wrote above piece of code, where did you used that piece of code?

Comment: how does your hashcode method look like?

Comment: Why are you subtracting hashcodes? IMO that's a bad way of comparing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just stumbled over the answer - compareto() {return 0;}  .... in a subclass far far away, so I did not realize it was there. Don't know, why I did not see this weeks ago - sorry for any inconveniance and thanks for the answers anyway.